# Replace string and pick certain values from a column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have my data in the given format

```
Column 1      Column 2
 $10,500.00   Father (FA)
 $165.00      Self (S)
 $315.00      Self (S)
```

I need to convert column 1 to number and separate column 2 in 2 fields as shown below

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3
10500       Father          FA
165         Self            S
315         Self            S
```

How can I do in Oracle

Comment: What datatype has column 1?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTR(col1, 1, INSTR(co1, '.') - 1), '$', ''), ',', '') AS col1,
    SUBSTR(col2, 1, INSTR(col2, ' ') - 1) AS col2,
    SUBSTR(col2, INSTR(col2, '(') + 1, INSTR(col2, ')') - INSTR(col2, '(') - 1) AS col3
FROM yourTable
```

This answer assumes that both original columns contain text.  If the first column is actually derived from a numeric column, then you should leverage Oracle's ability to format such data.  But the second and third output columns could still use the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a different approach, treating the first column as a number and using regular expressions to split the second column:

```
select to_number(Column1, 'L999G999G999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,'' NLS_CURRENCY = ''$'' '),
       regexp_substr(Column2, '[^(]*'),
       regexp_substr(Column2, '\((.*)\)', 1, 1, '', 1)
from test
```